# Vertical fill for text under table at end of section

Tags: tables, spacing

Hi I wasn't sure how to create a descriptive title for this issue. It is a bit weird. When I have a table near the end of a section and text is above and below it, the text will move to the bottom of the page to fill the entire page before the next section begins on the next page. I have attached some screen shots to show what I mean as well as a code example. Ideally what I would want is for the text to be directly under the table like always and the next section start on the next page i.e., just don't want the "verticle fill." Thanks, sorry if anything isn't clear

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

    \section{test}
    \blindtext[3]

    \subsection{more test}
    \blindtext[1]

    \begingroup

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{table}[t]
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \caption[test caption]{This is a test of the caption} 
        \label{tab-review}
        \footnotesize
        \centering
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
                M{0.2}M{0.09}M{0.08}M{0.15}M{0.13}M{0.14}M{0.085}}
            %
            \hline
            Reference                & Pub Year & \# Cases & Method             & Median Follow-up (months) & Good/Excellent coss & IBTR    \\ \hline
            Name1 [41]               & 2009     & 20       & test method        & 1 2                       & 82\%                & 0.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2010     & 20       & test method        & 1 2                     & 89\%                & 1.10\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2011     & 100      & test method        & 1 2                       & 82\%                & 1.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2012     & 20       & test method         & 1 2                     & 97\%                & 3.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method        & 1  2                      & 75\%                & 0.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method        & 53.1                      & 88\%                & 0.70\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method         & 18.9                      & 95\%                & 0.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 30       & test method        & 60                        & 73\%                & 3.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 98       & longer test method & 82.5                      & 62\%                & 11.00\% \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 98       & test method        & 82.5                      & 94\%                & 4.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2015     & 260      & test method         & 60                        & 100\%               & 1.40\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2015     & 569      & test method        & 36                        & 71\%                & NS      \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2016     & 141      & test method        & 60                        & 95\%                & 0.70\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2016     & 52       & test method       & 96                        & 64\%                & 7.70\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2017     & 669      & test method         & 72.2                      & NS                  & 0.50\%  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
    \endgroup
\blindtext[1]
\section{test}
\subsection{more test}
\blindtext[4]

\begingroup

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[t]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption[test caption]{This is a test of the caption} 
    \label{tab-review}
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
            M{0.2}M{0.09}M{0.08}M{0.15}M{0.13}M{0.14}M{0.085}}
        %
        \hline
        Reference                & Pub Year & \# Cases & Method             & Median Follow-up (months) & Good/Excellent coss & IBTR    \\ \hline
        Name1 [41]               & 2009     & 20       & test method        & 1 2                       & 82\%                & 0.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2010     & 20       & test method        & 1 2                     & 89\%                & 1.10\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2011     & 100      & test method        & 1 2                       & 82\%                & 1.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2012     & 20       & test method         & 1 2                     & 97\%                & 3.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method        & 1  2                      & 75\%                & 0.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method        & 53.1                      & 88\%                & 0.70\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method         & 18.9                      & 95\%                & 0.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 30       & test method        & 60                        & 73\%                & 3.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 98       & longer test method & 82.5                      & 62\%                & 11.00\% \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 98       & test method        & 82.5                      & 94\%                & 4.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2015     & 260      & test method         & 60                        & 100\%               & 1.40\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2015     & 569      & test method        & 36                        & 71\%                & NS      \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2016     & 141      & test method        & 60                        & 95\%                & 0.70\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2016     & 52       & test method       & 96                        & 64\%                & 7.70\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2017     & 669      & test method         & 72.2                      & NS                  & 0.50\%  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\endgroup
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble, then LaTeX has not to fill the complete page with text and can left at the bottom of the page some space ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\raggedbottom % <=======================================================


\begin{document}

    \section{test}
    \blindtext[3]

    \subsection{more test}
    \blindtext[1]

    \begingroup

    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{table}[t]
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \caption[test caption]{This is a test of the caption} 
        \label{tab-review}
        \footnotesize
        \centering
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
                M{0.2}M{0.09}M{0.08}M{0.15}M{0.13}M{0.14}M{0.085}}
            %
            \hline
            Reference                & Pub Year & \# Cases & Method             & Median Follow-up (months) & Good/Excellent coss & IBTR    \\ \hline
            Name1 [41]               & 2009     & 20       & test method        & 1 2                       & 82\%                & 0.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2010     & 20       & test method        & 1 2                     & 89\%                & 1.10\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2011     & 100      & test method        & 1 2                       & 82\%                & 1.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2012     & 20       & test method         & 1 2                     & 97\%                & 3.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method        & 1  2                      & 75\%                & 0.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method        & 53.1                      & 88\%                & 0.70\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method         & 18.9                      & 95\%                & 0.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 30       & test method        & 60                        & 73\%                & 3.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 98       & longer test method & 82.5                      & 62\%                & 11.00\% \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 98       & test method        & 82.5                      & 94\%                & 4.00\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2015     & 260      & test method         & 60                        & 100\%               & 1.40\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2015     & 569      & test method        & 36                        & 71\%                & NS      \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2016     & 141      & test method        & 60                        & 95\%                & 0.70\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2016     & 52       & test method       & 96                        & 64\%                & 7.70\%  \\
            Name1 [41]               & 2017     & 669      & test method         & 72.2                      & NS                  & 0.50\%  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
    \endgroup
\blindtext[1]
\section{test}
\subsection{more test}
\blindtext[4]

\begingroup

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[t]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \caption[test caption]{This is a test of the caption} 
    \label{tab-review}
    \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}%
            M{0.2}M{0.09}M{0.08}M{0.15}M{0.13}M{0.14}M{0.085}}
        %
        \hline
        Reference                & Pub Year & \# Cases & Method             & Median Follow-up (months) & Good/Excellent coss & IBTR    \\ \hline
        Name1 [41]               & 2009     & 20       & test method        & 1 2                       & 82\%                & 0.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2010     & 20       & test method        & 1 2                     & 89\%                & 1.10\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2011     & 100      & test method        & 1 2                       & 82\%                & 1.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2012     & 20       & test method         & 1 2                     & 97\%                & 3.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method        & 1  2                      & 75\%                & 0.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method        & 53.1                      & 88\%                & 0.70\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2013     & 20       & test method         & 18.9                      & 95\%                & 0.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 30       & test method        & 60                        & 73\%                & 3.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 98       & longer test method & 82.5                      & 62\%                & 11.00\% \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2014     & 98       & test method        & 82.5                      & 94\%                & 4.00\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2015     & 260      & test method         & 60                        & 100\%               & 1.40\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2015     & 569      & test method        & 36                        & 71\%                & NS      \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2016     & 141      & test method        & 60                        & 95\%                & 0.70\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2016     & 52       & test method       & 96                        & 64\%                & 7.70\%  \\
        Name1 [41]               & 2017     & 669      & test method         & 72.2                      & NS                  & 0.50\%  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\endgroup
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

and the second table:

[image: second page]